# Laravel create and auth login

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple registration where validation passes, but create doesn't fill up fullname and phone(I checked they are passed - by echoing).
I also tried by using `request()->input('fullname');` but I got same result.

For login after storing values this auth()->login($user) and auth()->attempt() both fails.

I don't know since uniqid for password is same as stored....

```
public function register(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'fullname' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'phone' => 'required'
        ]);

        $passcode = uniqid();

        $user = User::create([
            'fullname' => $request->fullname,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt($passcode),
            'phone' => $request->phone
        ]);

        if(User::sendEmail($passcode, $request->email,  $request->fullname)) {
            if (auth()->login($user)) {
                session()->flash('user', 'You have been logged in..');
                session()->flash('data', request());
                return redirect()->route('dashboard');
            }
        session()->flash('login', 'Not logged in.');
        }
        return redirect()->back();

    }

<form action="{{ route('register') }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full name">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
    <button type="submit">Continue</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I haven't used the built-in Auth system in Laravel in a long time, but for passwords in Laravel, I usually use `\Hash::make($password);`, not `bcrypt()`; might help, might not. Check the `public $fillable` array in your `User.php` model to see if `fullname` and `phone` can be mass-assigned (via `User::create()` method)

Comment: @TimLewis `bcrypt()` is just a helper for `Hash::make`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-bcrypt "You may use it as an alternative to the Hash facade." I suspect you're on to something with the `$fillable` parameter in the model.

Comment: @ceejayoz I figured they were related; so that's not an issue then.

Comment: Whats in your Model and Migration?

Comment: @Yeeooow migration same as one u get from laravel with string-phone and changed name to fullname. And model is empty I deleted user which I had and made new user. I just added send message method and imported phpmailer into it.

Comment: Why are you using phpmailer in Laravel? It already has a Mail class built-in you should use.

Comment: If you deleted the User model, chances are it's missing some useful stuff, and you should be telling it what columns are fillable in `$fillable`. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment.

Comment: @ceejayoz I know I just like phpmailer.