# Passing request through sessions in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

From my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50470738/laravel-create-and-auth-login) where I have't got answer I went deep  down into the problem and found out what it is:

```
session()->flash('data', request());
```

I thought this would work because I used it before in little different way:

```
session()->flash('data', request()->input('fullname'));
```

But when i submit that form from last question I had more than just registering the user, but first part was to register the user and redirect to page where the user is logged in and pass other form values.
It could work if I pass them as text one by one, but is there a way to pass whole request object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out just by adding `request()->all()` or `request(['those','that','are','needed'])`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `request()->all()` to return the data. If you just use `request()` it's just returning the `Request` class.